# Representation of the group of rotations on the space of spherical functions

Tags: representation-theory

On a project on how Representation theory can help improve the complexity of shape matching, I couldn't understand this result :

If $V$ is the space of spherical functions, consider the representation of the group of rotations on this space. Suppose that we can decompose V into a collection of one-dimensional representations, and $w_{1}$, ... $w_{n}$ an orthogonal basis corresponding to this decomposition. We have then $T(w_{i}) € Cw_{i}$ for all rotations T.

Can someone explain to me why is this true ? I think it has a link with Schur's Lemma but I'm not sure.

Also, do you know some sources on representation theory in shape matching ?

Thank you.